# Is there some genetic variance underlying music appreciation?

Tags: genetics, human-genetics

Is there any research done on the genetic variance for Music appreciation?

If not, why is there no genetic variance for this trait?

[image]

Comment: It is important to understand what `genetic reason behind ..` means. It usually makes much more sense to ask `Is there some genetic variance underlying music appreciation?`. You may want to have a look to [this](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13669/do-genes-play-a-role-in-the-athleticism-and-shape-of-a-person/13670#13670) and/or [this](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/11402/will-i-grow-taller-how-can-i-tell/12405#12405) post. You may, then eventually want to edit your question.

Comment: @Remi.b: Sounds better!

Comment: I wouldn't vote to close but I think your question deserves a little editing. `Is there some genetic variance underlying music appreciation?` Not `gene variance`. `Is there any research done on the gene responsible for Music appreciation?` This assumes there is only one gene. I'd suggest to stick to the formulation using `genetic variance`. I consider it is a detail but that might be important to you given that someone voted to close! What do you mean `If not, is there any reason its impossible to predict?` Does it mean `If not, why is there no genetic variance for this trait?`?

Comment: Yes, it looks much better to me! Well.. I personally have no idea! The only think I can say is that such studies in humans are likely to be biased due to the culture and assortative mating.

Comment: One can perhaps look at extremes: compare Beethoven (or any other musical genius) with lets say a great mathematician who has no appreciation for music. (That way you have normalized for basic intelligence). But these are just opinions.

Comment: Or otherwise if it is just about sound patterns (harmonics), their production and perception then the genomes of a songbird and a chicken can be compared.

Comment: @WYSIWYG: Mathematician and Music is actually kind of wrong as both need same region of brain might have some correlation: http://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/0214/13022014-Mathematical-beauty-activates-same-brain-region-as-great-art-Zeki

Comment: So wouldn't that just mean that music appreciation is correlated with general IQ ??

Comment: @WYSIWYG: I don't think so. Still I found this http://www.psmag.com/navigation/books-and-culture/classical-music-linked-to-high-intelligence-27959/

Comment: See that is what I was saying. There are no conclusive studies and this question is tending to "primarily opinion based". Did you consider the option of comparing songbird and chicken?

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely **on** topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 2013, 
**Dr. Liisa Ukkola-Vuoti**, *University of Helsinki, Finland*, done a detailed GWCNV(Genome-Wide Copy Number Variation) Analysis of certain group of people for musical creativity and aptitude.

### Genome-Wide Copy Number Variation Analysis in Extended Families and Unrelated Individuals Characterized for Musical Aptitude and Creativity in Music

- They did a Genome Wide Copy Number Variations (CNVs) in five extended
  pedigrees and in 172 unrelated subjects characterized for musical
  aptitude and creative functions in music
- Muscial Aptitude is taken as Sum of Scores of Auditory structuring ability, Seashores test for pitch and for time. Along with data on creativity in music was surveyed using a web-based questionnaire.
- **Several CNVRs containing genes that affect neurodevelopment, learning
  and memory were detected.**
- A **deletion at 5q31.1 covering the protocadherin-α gene cluster (Pcdha 1-9)** was found co-segregating with **low music test scores (COMB)** in both sample sets. Pcdha is involved in neural migration, differentiation and synaptogenesis.
- Creativity in music was found to co-segregate with a duplication covering **glucose mutarotase gene (GALM) at 2p22**. GALM has influence on serotonin
  release and membrane trafficking of the human serotonin transporter.
- Genes related to serotonergic systems have been shown to associate not only with psychiatric disorders but also with creativity and music perception.
- Both, Pcdha and GALM, are related to the serotonergic systems influencing cognitive and motor functions, important for music perception and practice.
- A **1.3 Mb duplication was identified in a subject with low COMB scores** in the **region previously linked with absolute pitch (AP) at 8q24**.
- No differences in the CNV burden was detected among the high/low music test scores or creative/non-creative groups.

> In summary, CNVs and genes found in this study are related to
>   cognitive functions. Our result suggests new candidate genes for music
>   perception related traits and supports the previous results from AP
>   study.

### Source:

[1] [Genome-Wide Copy Number Variation Analysis in Extended Families and Unrelated Individuals Characterized for Musical Aptitude and Creativity in Music](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3584088)

[2] [Musical Aptitude Is Associated with AVPR1A-Haplotypes](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2678260/)

Comment: Interesting study, thank you! It is worth noting that probably these two traits (creativity and aptitude) may be highly correlated with IQ.

Comment: @Remi.b: Yes they are. Thanks for not closing this question.

Comment: @Remi.b no those traits would correlate more strongly to expertise in a specific field rather than general intelligence. iq measures not genius which is what these genes could potentially spawn with others of course